# Перечислениe enum Keys для сочетания клавиш

Tags: c#, winforms

приветствую. пишу в WForms маленькую утилиту под windows , которая расширяет возможности буфера копирования. вопрос в том как сказать программе что нажал cntrl+v. например в перечислении Keys находится скан коды для клавиш а есть ли enum для комбинации например ctrl + V ?

Comment: Вы только в своём приложении хотите расширить возможности буфера или глобально во всей системе?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov только в приложении

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl отдельно от V передаётся и в Keys его нету. Реализовать вопрос можно через WinAPI.
Нужно добавить namespace:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

Затем использовать WinAPI

```
    struct INPUT
        {
            public UInt32 Type;
            public MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT Data;
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        struct MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public MOUSEINPUT Mouse;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public KEYBDINPUT Keyboard;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public HARDWAREINPUT Hardware;
        }

        #pragma warning disable 649
        struct MOUSEINPUT
        {
            public Int32 X;
            public Int32 Y;
            public UInt32 MouseData;
            public UInt32 Flags;
            public UInt32 Time;
            public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct KEYBDINPUT
        {
            public UInt16 Vk;
            public UInt16 Scan;
            public UInt32 Flags;
            public UInt32 Time;
            public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
        }

        struct HARDWAREINPUT
        {
            public UInt32 Msg;
            public UInt16 ParamL;
            public UInt16 ParamH;
        }
```

Класс который использует функционал выше:

```
public static class A
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 numberOfInputs, INPUT[] inputs, Int32 sizeOfInputStructure);

            public static void SendCtrlV()
            {
                var key = Keys.V;
                var down = MakeInput(key, true);
                var up = MakeInput(key, false);

                var ctrlDown = MakeInput(Keys.LControlKey, true);
                var ctrlUp = MakeInput(Keys.LControlKey, false);
                SendInput(4, new INPUT[4] { ctrlDown, down, up, ctrlUp },Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
            }
            private static INPUT MakeInput(Keys key, bool down)
            {
                return new INPUT
                {
                    Type = 1,
                    Data = new MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT
                    {
                        Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT
                        {
                            Vk = (UInt16)key,
                            Scan = 0,
                            Flags = (uint) (down ? 0 : 0x0002),
                            Time = 0,
                            ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо. буду пользоваться

Comment: @Сергей как вы наверное поняли уже этот вариант глобально для всех приложений нажимает Ctrl+V и работает именно в том поле, которое сейчас активно.